# How to name the functionality of "suspend/hibernate and restore application execution" - something like Hibernate in Windows, but only for one Thread

Tags: frameworks

I'm working on a solution to "suspend / hibernate and resume" an application written in C # /. Net and looking for the right name for it.

This solution "hibernate" the completed thread, allows you to save its state (stack, local data ...) to disk and restart (from hibernation).
Something like the hibernation function in the Windows operating system, working only on individual threads in .Net.
The key in this solution is that the thread lives very long. Such a thread can be serialized (at the execution point)/hibernate, saved to disk and resumed after a few days (even on another computer).

The name "Hibernate" would be appropriate, but is immediately associated with ORM Hibernate.

The name should reflect the intentions of the solution and be understood by potential users.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is wrong with suspend/resume, terms already used by any thread class in any environment? If those words are too fancy for application level, user perspective, you could just use start/stop. I would stay clear from hibernation, that implies long term.

Comment: IMO suspend / resume is associated with thread operations that are short-lived. The key issue in this solution is the thread that lives long. Such a thread can be serialized/hibernate (at the execution point), saved to disk and resumed after a few days (even on another computer). Thanks for the info, I will update the question

Comment: If, instead of threads, you focused on units of work, then suspending and resuming units of work would be possible.

Comment: see [On the troubles of naming and terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6583/31260)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Application checkpointing has similar functionality. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing